# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '####' for key 'key_id' on update statement

Tags: mysql, sqlexception

I am trying to update a record in a table and it's throwing the following error:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '5452' for key 'device_id'
```

from

```
update device_info set  serial_number = '728015162815' , ip_address = '192.168.77.121'   , location_code = '1', battery_status = 'Not Charging : 36%'       
where device_id = 5452
```

What is going on here?  I can understand this error on an **insert**, but this is getting thrown on an **update statement**.

Comment: `SHOW TRIGGERS`?

Comment: @BillKarwin  Thanks, I just realized someone added triggers to a table w/o informing me.  They were the cause of the dupe key error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, comments above show the solution.

Mysterious errors that seem impossible given the SQL statement you run might be caused by another SQL statement. How can this happen? It could be run by a trigger that is spawned by your UPDATE.

The trigger might be inserting a row to some other table, resulting in a duplicate key error. Or the trigger could change a value in a unique column of the current row being updated, that could also result in the same error.

This will show you what triggers exist:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

Comment: Spot on, it was because of a trigger which was inserting a record in other table whose primary key was small int. :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got similar error but the issue was not due to triggers or other actions. It was due to heap table size shortage.

I had to increase the size as follows

```
[mysqld]
tmp_table_size = 265M
max_heap_table_size = 265M
```

inspired by: [MySQL: 1062 Duplicate entry ‘’ for key ‘group_key](https://medium.com/@leyo/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key-e9deed8d596b)